# How to enable JSP pages in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a simple JSP page that I want to show. I use Spring Boot on Tomcat 8 server.

test.jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

I configured the path to the JSP in `application.properties`:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

My Project structure (maven):

```
src/main/java
src/main/resources
WebContent/WEB-INF/test.jsp
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/web/test")
public class MyController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String getMissingContent(ModelMap model) {
        model.put("time", new Date());
        model.put("message", "testmsg");
            return "test";
    }
}

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
}
```

Result: I'm not seeing the HTML page, but just the string "test" on a blank page. Why?

Comment: Please try with `@Controller` instead of `@RestController` for starters.

Comment: Long story short, `@RestController` will regard "test" as the response itself, while `@Controller` will regard "test" as the view to be rendered. If the prefix and suffix are set-up OK, the "test" view should be rendered then.

Comment: Would you mind adding this as a real answer? This was the cause.

Comment: If it was just that, sure. I will prepare an answer shortly, referencing the docs too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spring MVC WebApp using Spring Boot does not launch "\*.jsp" file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37817173/spring-mvc-webapp-using-spring-boot-does-not-launch-jsp-file)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just convert `@RestController` to `@Controller` for your `MyController`. The reason for the observed behavior is the difference between `@RestController` and `@Controller`. According to [the docs for @RestController](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestController.html):

> [@RestController is] a convenience annotation that is itself annotated with @Controller and @ResponseBody.

Because of the `@ResponseBody` annotation, the method's return value is regarded as the response itself.

Spring MVC's `@Controller` annotation will expect the method's return value to be the name of the view to be rendered (so that the rendered view can be returned as the response body). If the prefix and suffix for your views are set up correctly, the model will be passed to the view and the view will be rendered.

In your case, you meant to pass the model to the "test" view to be rendered (and returned), but the hidden `@ResponseBody` ruined your plans and "test" (string) was returned as is, as the response body.

Answer (score 1):

`@RestController` will regard "test" as the response itself

`@Controller` will regard "test" as the view to be rendered.

If the prefix and suffix are set-up OK, the "test" view should be rendered then.